# woocommerce update meta when refunded

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to update the `post_meta` of woocommerce order when ever a refund initiated manually in woocommerce admin. For this I tried `woocommerce_order_processing_status_refunded` as the order will be in `wc-processing` state before I initiate refunds. But the `post_meta` is not getting updated whereas, the same code worked perfectly when hooked to `woocommerce_order_status_refunded`. Any idea on how to use the refunds event only when the previous status is `wc-processing?